# Relationship between independence and consistency: Why does Con$(\mathsf{ZFC})\implies\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC+\phi})$ imply $\phi$ can't be disproved

Tags: logic, set-theory

Forgive me, because I'm sure this question has been asked before because of how central it is to set theory/logic, but I cannot find it on stackexchange. If someone finds that this is a duplicate, please take this question down. My question is about how exactly independence proofs work. I get the following idea, but there's one thing that evades me when it's explained. Here's in general how it goes. Suppose I have a formula $\phi$ which I wish to prove is independent of a theory $T$. Why must we show that if $T$ is consistent, then $T+\phi$ is consistent, and separately, if $T$ is consistent, then $T+\neg\phi$ is consistent?

The specific disconnect is that I'm not seeing why showing the consistency of $T+\phi$ implies $\neg\phi$ cannot be proven in $T$.  I know that consistency means you cannot prove a contradiction from the theory, but I'm not sure how this implies that the negation cannot be proven. There are surely other ways to prove $\neg\phi$ than a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\lnot \phi$ were provable in $T$ (by any proof technique whatsoever), then it would also be provable in $T + \phi$, since the validity of a proof isn't harmed by adding more axioms.  Since $T + \phi$ trivially proves $\phi$, that shows that $T + \phi$ proves $\phi \land \lnot \phi$, a contradiction, so $T+\phi$ is inconsistent.

The contrapositive of this statement is that if $T + \phi$ is consistent, then $T$ does not prove $\lnot \phi$.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're overthinking this.

Suppose $T\vdash\neg\varphi$. Don't worry about **how** this is the case, just observe that this a fortiori means $S\vdash \neg\varphi$ for every theory $S\supseteq T$: **adding axioms doesn't lose theorems**. In particular, this holds for $S=T\cup\{\varphi\}$. But if $T\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash\neg\varphi$ then $T\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash\varphi\wedge\neg\varphi$ (since $S\vdash\alpha$ for every $\alpha\in S$, and $S\vdash\alpha$ and $S\vdash\beta$ implies $S\vdash\alpha\wedge\beta$), so if $T\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash\neg\varphi$ then $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ is inconsistent.

Comment: I am *way* overthinking this. Thanks a lot!